# Detecting compatibility breaks of dependencies

Tags: javascript

Coming from C++ and being fairly new to JavaScript, I find myself reasoning about how to verify the stability of a 3rd party dependency. For instance, I'm currently upgrading an existing WebGL engine which uses Three.js as a convenience framework and I found that over the last versions, multiple object properties and features the engine relies on were removed.

IIUC, there is no a priori way to detect such breaks unless functionality or properties which were removed are actively used - this makes sense to me, since you can only know at run-time what is actually accessed and thus cannot determine whether a property actually exists until it is used in some way. First question now: is that assumptuion correct?

If so, the only way I can think of to automatically verify the stability (or point out breaks) of an API (I refer to API both in terms of functionality and object properties) is to maintain a suite of unit tests (or similar) which basically use everything the actual code uses and every time a 3rd party dependency is updated. Depending on the number of distinct APIs in use in one's codebase, this can get tedious very, very quickly.

My current approach, since unit tests don't currently exist at all, is to manually wade through the changelogs, find all references to removed APIs and trying to figure out how to replace existing functionality which is now broken without breaking more things. This clearly sucks.

I would hope that projects try to maintain compatibility as well as possible and instate policies for doing so, like the [Node.js stability policy](https://nodejs.org/en/get-involved/development/#stability-policy) but after doing some preliminary searches, I didn't find much on the topic (or I used the wrong key words).

Fianlly, I find myself asking the following questions:

- is there a consensus in the community on how to handle the problem 
  above?
- do there exist tools to achieve a solution?
- are those solutions scalable?

Comment: Many Node packages (as well as Node.js itself) use [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org). The version number of a dependency may be a hint as to whether the API is compatible with a previous version or not, at least in theory.

Comment: @GOTO0: Looking at Three.js, they seem to version only like `r78`, `r79`and so on. Minor versions and patch-levels don't seem to matter to them. :)